# ReferenceError: require is not defined - server.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

I am working on a basic app with a server, but receiving the 'ReferenceError: require is not defined' error.
Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const passport = require("passport");
const userRoutes=require('./routes/userRoutes.cjs')

dotenv.config()
```

Here is the error I am getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh1O5.png

Does anyone have any ideas why I am getting this error?

Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh1O5.png

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: I run it by typing 'nodemon server.js'.

Answer (score 0):

By default `require()` is not a valid function in client-side javascript. I recommend you look into [require.js](https://requirejs.org/) as this does extend the client side to provide you with that function.